# ${credentials-iot:ThingName} causing AccessDeniedException when used in an IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iot

I've followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/authorizing-direct-aws.html to set up the following resources:

**A DynamoDB table with name H42318K04D**

**IAM role with name "IoTCertificateExchangedRole" and the following inline policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:<accountId>:table/${credentials-iot:ThingName}"
    }
}
```

**and trust policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "credentials.iot.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**An IoT Thing with name "H42318K04D" and attached active IoT certificate with the following certificate policy:**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iot:AssumeRoleWithCertificate",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:<accountId>:rolealias/IoTCertificateExchangedRoleAlias"
  }
}
```

**An IoT role alias with name "IoTCertificateExchangedRoleAlias", which is associated with the "IoTCertificateExchangedRole" role mentioned earlier.**

I was able to obtain temporary credential via the curl command:

```
curl --cert device.crt --key device.key -H "z-amzn-iot-thingname: H42318K04D" https://<IoT credential provider endpoint>/role-aliases/IoTCertificateExchangedRoleAlias/credentials
```

And use the temporary credentials to call `aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name H42318K04D --region us-west-2`. However, whenever the IAM inline policy uses the `${credentials-iot:ThingName}` variable as indicated above, the call failed with:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeTable operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<accountId>:assumed-role/IoTCertificateExchangedRole/db296615613581f5a82e70ae071e49a45c561e3b95598f1dd3c3194f19fcb4ab is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:<accountId>:table/H42318K04D because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:DescribeTable action
```

When I updated the inline policy to the following and made the call again using the same set of credentials:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:<accountId>:table/H42318K04D"
    }
}
```

It correctly returned the table information.

So, ${credentials-iot:ThingName} does not appear to be functioning correctly?

Update: I did notice that the curl command always returns temporary credentials regardless of whether/what is supplied as the `z-amzn-iot-thingname` header.